PyInstaller & Keras Model - add-data to create onefile with h5 and labels file
I wrote a TKinter interface to analyze images against a local Keras model. To make it easier for usual users I want to convert it as an executable file in Win11 - but later on the executable file should also work for Mac. In Python I load the Keras model and the labels.txt in this way:
# Load the model
model = load_model("keras_Model.h5", compile=False)

# Load the labels
class_names = open("labels.txt", "r").readlines()

to create the .exe file I use the command line:
python -m PyInstaller --onefile myfile.py --add-data "keras_model.h5;." --add-data "labels.txt;."

PyInstaller builds the exe file without issues.
But when I try to start the .exe file I get an error, saying the model can't be found - as the model is loaded first, probably the same appears with the label.txt
OSError: No file or directory found at keras_Model.h5

I tried some things:

Use : instead of ; in the command line
Adding a folder like model\keras_Model.h5
Using the spec file instead of adding the data in the command line

I assume I make a really stupid mistake, but I don't get it...
